# Ionic: I'm unable to create tabs properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-tabs

I've used to create tabs with some content on it using the following code:

```
    <div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
    <div class="tabs">
      <a class="tab-item active" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
        Test
    <div class="item item-avatar">
      <div ng-bind="profile.img_element"></div>
    <h2 ng-bind="profile.name"></h2>
    <p ng-bind="profile.points"></p><p> points</p> 

    </div>
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-star"></i>
        Favorites
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i>
        Settings
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, my problem is that the tabs doesn't switch, and on the top of that I've been unable to set the content of the tab 'Test' properly.

I did some searches, but still didn't find a solution.

I don't have enough experience with Ionic, So any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
href="#" should not be '#' for every tab. '#' means default root url. So when you click on every page it redirect on same page. You need to set content using 'ion-nav-view' for tab view.
```

Please study [this](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz) CodePen for more guid

Comment: I copied some code from the one you suggested: but I got "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for the tab linked html files.

Comment: Can you update a more code including html file and routing or create codepen so I can check it and help you.

Comment: I solved all the problems: after fixing many bugs in my app. Your code is helpful. Thank you.